# Android click on notification does not open the attached Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I want to open an Activity when I click on the notification from the Status bar. I have seen this answered on StackOverflow but none of these answers work for me. 
This issue is only seen on Lollipop devices and best way to reproduce is:
1. launch the app.
2. Back ground the app.
3. Receive a push notification.
4. Click on the notification and try with 3-4 push notifications.

Below is my code: I have also tried the following:

1. adding Intent.ACTION_MAIN
2. Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER to the intent
3. PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT.
4. android:exported="true" in my AndroidManifest.xml

but nothing works. I am seeing this issue only on Lollipop devices.
Please note I see this issue intermittently. Is this something related to the intent getting cached and not getting delivered. Please help.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent(context, payload);
Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)
            .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(payload.getMessage())
            .setTicker(payload.getMessage())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(soundUri);

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context, NotificationPayload payload) {
    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeepLinkActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setPackage(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationHelper.KEY_NOTIFICATION_PAYLOAD, payload);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: Have you set the pendingIntent to your notification builder?

Comment: i have the same issue.. no luck up to now

Answer (score 1):

try adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK flag in the intent

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

this seems to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the pending intent in the notification setContentIntent method?

Try this, it works for me on all api versions

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Ok I tested on kitkat and it works fine. I am seeing this issue ONLY on lollipop devices. @androholic does it work for you on lollipop?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the code I just tested on lollipop and it works fine. Also, remove requestId. a value of 0 in place of requestId in the pending intent itself should suffice. Try the above code.

Comment: I am using ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. All the code I have posted happens in the overriden getNotification method of the receiver which has the return type of Notification. I dont see a way to call notificationManager.notify(). May sound silly but kindly help how do I use NotificationManager with this setup.

Comment: You have two options:
1. Return the notificationBuilder.build() in the getNotification() method and use the notification as per your convenience.
2. Use the above code and display the notification using notification manager in the getnotification() method and return null.

Comment: This does not work for me. Have you also set exported="true" for the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml?